# rabbitmq ssl authentication

Tags: rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, authorization

I have a query regarding SSL authentication in RabbitMQ.

I am currently using a RabbitMQ Docker container with SSL authentication enabled. Instead of relying on traditional username-password credentials, I want the authentication process to be based solely on the client's public key.

When a client attempts to connect to the RabbitMQ server, the server should take the client's public key and compare it to a stored list of authorized clients' public keys. If there's a match, the server should grant access.

In ZeroMQ, there's a convenient load_certificates method that allows for loading clients' public keys from a folder and using them for the login process.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for ?
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

"RabbitMQ relies on Erlang's TLS implementation. It assumes that all trusted CA certificates are added to the server certificate bundle."
Here you can create an all_cert.bundle file.

And / or use:
RabbitMQ Certificate Trust Store
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-trust-store

Comment: @nogabemist did you find this useful?